# VS 2015 std::char_traits<char16_t> operations

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, wchar-t, char16-t, char-traits

At my workplace, we changed string type (which holds internationalized characters) for from `std::wstring` to `std::u16string` after VS 2015(Update 3) compiler upgrade.

Due to this, we are seeing loads of performance regressions such as [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3130786/std-u16string-copying-performance-much-worse-than-std-wstring).

The profiler analysis reveals that `std::u16string`'s `std::char_traits<char16_t>` operations such as `copy`, `compare`, `find` and `assign` are the most hit and are taking longer than `std::wstring`'s `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` counterparts.

These `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` operations are written in terms of `std::wmem*` and `std::char_traits<char16_t>` operations are written in terms of `for loops`.

If we change these traits operations for `char16_t` type (or `std::u16string`) to use our own customized traits, we are seeing performance improvements with performance comparable to `std::wstring`.

We are planning to write our own custom traits (until MS fixes it for next version of VS) as follows

```
struct string_custom_traits : public std::char_traits<char16_t>
{
    static const char16_t * copy(char16_t* dest, const char16_t* src, size_t count)
    {
        return (count == 0 ? src : (char16_t*)std::memcpy(dest, src, count * sizeof(char16_t)));
    }               
};
```

Would that be OK? Are there any problems with this approach ?

Comment: This might be a better fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You definitely can't use `memchr` and `memset` that way, and maybe not `memcmp` either, depending on endianness.